Rebuilding ElasticBeanstalk instance willl not rebuild
I set my ElasticBeanstalk instance to rebuild to see if it would get a cronjob to start running - everything else was fine.  But it now won't rebuild and I'm getting this error

Stack named 'awseb-e-tcy56g97i6-stack' aborted operation. Current
state: 'CREATE_FAILED' Reason: The following resource(s) failed to
create: [AWSEBV2LoadBalancerListener443].

Can anyone advice me what I need to do?

The first thing I’d do is go to the CloudFormation console and check the Events tab of the specific Elastic Beanstalk stack that failed. This will often give you more direct information about what’s going wrong.
If this is all you could find in the events,

Stack named 'awseb-e-tcy56g97i6-stack' aborted operation. Current state: 'CREATE_FAILED' Reason: The following resource(s) failed to
create: [AWSEBV2LoadBalancerListener443].

here are a few things that come to mind:
1. SSL/TLS Certificate
Since you’re using HTTPS, Elastic Beanstalk needs to create a listener on port 443. Make sure you have a valid SSL certificate in AWS Certificate Manager (ACM) for your domain if at all you use ACM. Also, verify that the certificate is in the correct region and linked to the right load balancer. If the certificate isn’t properly configured, the listener will most likely fail.
2. Security Group or VPC Configuration
Check that your security group allows inbound traffic on port 443. In the VPC that your setup is located, confirm that subnets, routing tables, and network ACLs are correctly configured to permit traffic on this port. These settings can cause issues with the listener setup if misconfigured.
3. Elastic IP and AWS Limits
If you’re using an Elastic IP, ensure it’s properly linked, and check that you haven’t hit any regional limits for Elastic IPs or load balancers. AWS also has limits on the number of load balancers or listeners, so you may want to review those as well.
These are the things I can think of. Hope it helps.

really?  Everything was working so why wouldn't it rebuild.  All conditions above were met.
